# Is replacing existing DLL without re-registering it possible?

Tags: dll, updates, regsvr32

I need to update an existing DLL file that is already in use for our client-software that is installed on 400+ computers. This DLL file exists today and is already registered with regsvr32.exe when the software was installed.

The problem is that I cannot easily run the regsvr32.exe command without changing the entire update process, which is a mayor hassle as it is ancient and no documentation exists on it.

So I wondered if I actually have to re-register the dll file, or if replacing the file is enough. I tried searching for more information on this, but so far came up blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you created the DLL.

If you broke the **binary compatibility** you must re-register the DLL using regsvr32. If you mantained the binary compatibility copying the new DLL should be enough.

VB6 had an option called "Binary Compatibility" which helped to deal with these issues ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733715(v=vs.60).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733715%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)). I don't know if VC++ or VS.NET provide something similar.

Greetings,
edu